# Left join and show the non-foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables that I'm joining, `Users` and `Addresses`.

The Users table has a `unique (but not primary) key called userID`.
The `Addresses` table has a `primary key called userID`.

I'm trying to `left-join` the tables so that I get all the info from the Users table regardless if it has a match in the Addresses table, so I used

```
select * from users u left join addresses a on a.userID = u.userID
```

This works, but it only shows userID's if there is a match. How do I get the userID regardless if there's a match or not?

Edit: The following image shows what my current query (left join) returns:

[image: Test Data]

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` should be doing exactly what you describe.  Can you show some sample data of what it is happening, and what you want?

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: The result should show the userID for Dwight Schrute, but doesn't.

Comment: what actually you wants? i mean result. than your image

Comment: There's no logical explanation for the behavior you are describing. Every row from the users table should be returned by your query. Perhaps the issue is that you aren't seeing the rows because the resultset is not ordered, and the tool you are using is limiting the number of rows returned. For completeness, I suggest you add an `ORDER BY u.userID` and compare the results to a query from the users table, ordered the same way.

Comment: @spencer7593 When I run the query on phpmyadmin, it does execute correctly (and shows all the information in the users table) however when I run it from my php page, it gives me this issue.

Comment: @General_Twhyckenham: with that information, it's now clear what the problem is. You have columns of the same name in the tables. See my answer.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks! Now I understand the problem as well, and it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's clear what the problem is.

There's nothing "wrong" with the query, except that it is returning multiple expressions (columns) with the same alias. And one of them is overriding the other. (Not in terms of the resultset being returned, all the columns and rows are there; the issue is with how your PHP script is processing the resultset. If you are referencing the values from the row by "association" (using the column name), only one of the column values gets referenced.

So, one way to fix that, is to qualify the columns in the query:

```
SELECT u.userID
     , u.blah
     , a.userID  AS a_userID
     , a.blah    AS a_blah
  FROM users u 
  LEFT
  JOIN addresses a
   ON ...
```

such that all column aliases are unique. Then all of those column names will be available by "association" in your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Using the query you provided should give a result in the `u.userID` column regardless of if it had a corresponding address. The `a.userID` column would only have data in the rows that were joined with an address.

You could change to:

```
select u.*, a.address from users u left join addresses a on a.userID = u.userID
```

Which would select only the relevant parts of the `address` and keep the whole `u`.

Comment: Interesting. This works, and I'll upvote your answer. I'm just wondering (as I'm sure the other commenters are) what's causing the issue with the original query. Thanks!

Comment: I would have accepted your answer, but Spencer gives a more detailed explanation of the problem, which would be more useful for people in the future with the same issue.